# Script/API to generate customizable QR code

Tags: library, barcode

For a work project, I am looking for a script/API (preferably PHP or JavaScript) that allows me to generate a customizable QR code from a string of text.

By customizable I mean that I would like to be able to add a logo to the center of the QR code, modify the color of the QR code, the shapes of the squares in the corners, and, if possible, the general shape of the modules that make up the QR code. Basically, a similar set of modifications as can be seen in this web application:

https://www.unitag.io/qrcode

I have searched high and low, but the only scripts I can generate plain QR codes that cannot be customized. The solution does not necessarily have to be free, but I cannot seem to find anyone offering a script or API I can integrate into a web application. Whenever I do find a service offering customizable QR codes, it is always a paid (web)application on its own. Are there absolutely no solutions available that I can possibly integrate into a web application?

Comment: With PHP, can't you use the imagemagick functions to modify the "plain QR"? If the QR was created with highest redundancy, a small image put inside shouldn't render it unreadable.

Comment: One thing to remember is that the more you change specific elements (such as the squares in the corner) the less likely it is to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found exactly what you're looking for, Advanced Custom QR Code Generator. It costs $35 but allows you to,

- Customize colors
- Add shapes at corners of the QR code
- Embed a logo at the center
- Works with PHP

## [Advanced Custom QR Code Generator](http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-custom-qr-code-generator/5979898) ($35)

> This is the most advanced custom QR code generator script which lets your user change QR code from shapes to colors, even embed logos to it. Now, no more boring black and white squared QR codes. This advanced PHP QR code script lets your user design their very own QR code all by themself by choosing among 15000 style combinations of shapes with unlimited colors. The script is adsense ready so you can generate revenue easily. Also comes with an easy installer. Full source code, no encryption.
>
> [image: Example QR Codes]

Comment: In the meantime I have already built my implementation, although somewhat more limited using the following library: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

This looks like a great library which fits my original requirements of this question, so I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks :-)